# PHP SAFE MODE problem on host server when installing Sugar CRM

Tags: php, web-hosting, sugarcrm

I am trying to install Sugar community edition to our host server, but I am getting the PHP SAFE MODE ERRROR, and installation can not proceed. I see that the safe mode is turned off/on in the php.ini, but I dont have access to that file on the server..... Are there any work-arounds this??? I tried with editing the htaccess file like ive googled some suggestions, but nothing worked.. :/

All advices appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than asking your host if they can turn it on you don't have any options unless you switch from a shared server to a VPS. You can find a preety good offer at about 50$/month if you don't need anything much. Or, find a host that allows PHP mode turned on, altough I don't think you'll find any...

Comment: boh...yeah i assumed. I thaught maybe some changes in the Sugar installation files are possible, to avoid this..

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Sugar, but if at any point it has to write some files to the server, you most likely need php safe mode off.

Comment: some hosts even allow own "ini" settings in the users domain. we have a host her for example where i put a php.ini file into a folder and all php scripts then are being executed with that options from that ini file